# ActiveMQ Artemis failure to create Netty connection

Tags: connection, activemq-artemis

I get a failure when ActiveMQ Artemis attempts to make a Netty connection. I am showing the logs below. I have checked that the host is resolvable and it is. My host is a Kubernetes Pod, and I am running a stateful set of 4 pods

```
2022-04-11 09:46:30,441 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2022-04-11 09:46:30,485 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2022-04-11 09:46:30,791 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: eric-oss-jms-svc-amq-primary-1.eric-oss-jms-svc-amq-primary.liamtest.svc.cluster.local
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1505) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1364) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1298) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1248) [java.base:]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [java.base:]
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106) [netty-resolver-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:206) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:1008) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:516) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503) [netty-transport-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.72.Final.jar:4.1.72.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.20.0.jar:]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `java.net.UnknownHostException` here is coming from the JVM itself:

```
java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get
```

There's nothing that Netty or ActiveMQ Artemis can do about it. According to [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html), this exception is:

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

This problem is almost certainly environmental, although technically speaking it might also be a bug in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping the host using cmd **ping hostname**
If the ping not working do the below steps

1. Configure the host in the hosts file which is present at the location C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
   eg- 192.168.202.7 test.xyz.com
2. Do the same on the server side as well.
3. Restart the server.
4. Try pinging the server again.

By following the above steps this issue will get resolved.